# ifelse statement inside for loop R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am currently working with a very large dataset of elevations for which I need to attribute certain temperatures for each row based on binned elevation in 10m intervals. Because the dataset is so large, I cannot write a simple loop. I've created a smaller, fake dataset to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.

```
elevation <- seq(0, 100, 10)

e <- runif(n=100,min=0,max=100)
lettertype <- c(rep("a", 25), rep("b", 25), rep("c", 50))
x <- data.frame(e, lettertype)

Winter <- runif(n=10, min=10, max=15)
Spring <- runif(n=10, min=12, max=16)
Summer <- runif(n=10, min=14, max=20)
Fall   <- runif(n=10, min=11, max=16)
elevbin <- c("0 to 10", "10 to 20", "20 to 30", "30 to 40", "40 to 50", 
              "50 to 60", "60 to 70", "70 to 80", "80 to 90", "90 to 100")
y <- data.frame(elevbin, Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall)

Wintertemp <- c()
for (i in 1:length(y$Winter)){
  for (j in 1:length(elevation)){
    for (k in 1:length(x$e)){
      Wintertemp <- c(Wintertemp, (ifelse(x$e[k] >= elevation[j] & x$e < elevation[j+1],  y$Winter[i], NA)))
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially elevation is a vector which will tell the for loop the elevations within each bin (again this must be automated due to the size of the dataset, spanning 200 elevation bins).

- The dataframe x is an example of the raw elevation data I had, the column "lettertype" is not important, it was just an add-on to turn the vector e into a dataframe.
- The dataframe y has the information on which temperatures (by season, in this example I only use Winter but I need to do this for each season) are represented in each elevation bin.
- I want to cbind the output to the dataframe x

For example:

```
head(x)
          e lettertype
1  5.801268          a
2 99.115869          a
3 31.928297          a
4 25.886745          a
5 93.288743          a
6 23.496359          a

y
     elevbin   Winter
1    0 to 10 12.51486
2   10 to 20 14.14977
3   20 to 30 10.19768
4   30 to 40 12.63925
5   40 to 50 10.18445
6   50 to 60 10.91821
7   60 to 70 13.00326
8   70 to 80 11.89128
9   80 to 90 13.88241
10 90 to 100 12.33358
```

So I would like my outcome to be:

```
head(x)
          e lettertype   Winter
1  5.801268          a 12.51486
2 99.115869          a 12.33358
3 31.928297          a 12.63925
4 25.886745          a 10.19768
5 93.288743          a 12.33358
6 23.496359          a 10.19768
```

In simpler terms I want to assign the correct temperature for each elevation(e) in dataframe x, based on the temperatures from the elevation bins.

Currently the code returns a vector of length 1100000 with NAs and the first number in the winter vector, which is not correct. The outcome should be the same length as the x dataframe.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your existing loop work, does it give expected output? It would be good to provide expected results dataframe, maybe there is a better way of doing things, instead of trying to debug/improve your existing code. If we know input and expected output, we might try other things. By the way, this existing loop returns vector with 1.1Mln values...

Comment: I would also recommend providing additional information of what you want to achieve. Instead of focussing on the technical issue try to explain in simple words what you want to achieve. I, for example, don't quite understand how "e", "elevation" and the bins relate to each other. It would potentially also make sense to provide some real values which makes it easier for us to understand your goal.

Comment: The existing loop does not work. I updated my question with the current outcome and the expected outcome, hopefully this provides more information. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `for` loop or `ifelse`. You can `merge` the two data frames if you create appropriate columns first:

```
elevation <- seq(0, 100, 10)

e <- c(seq(0, 99, 1))
elev_floor <- 10 * floor(e / 10)
x <- data.frame(e, elev_floor)

Winter <- runif(n=10, min=10, max=15)
Spring <- runif(n=10, min=12, max=16)
Summer <- runif(n=10, min=14, max=20)
Fall   <- runif(n=10, min=11, max=16)
elevbin <- c("0 to 10", "10 to 20", "20 to 30", "30 to 40", "40 to 50", 
             "50 to 60", "60 to 70", "70 to 80", "80 to 90", "90 to 100")
elev_floor <- seq(0, 90, 10)
y <- data.frame(elevbin, elevmin, Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall)

merge(x, y)
```

Result:

```
      e elev_floor   elevbin elevmin   Winter   Spring   Summer     Fall
1     0          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
2     1          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
3     2          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
4     3          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
5     4          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
6     5          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
7     6          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
8     7          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
9     8          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
10    9          0   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
11   10         10   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
12   11         10   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
13   12         10   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
14   13         10   0 to 10       0 12.53781 13.01907 16.74989 15.22208
```

If your bins are more complicated than in your example, than you can adjust the calculation of `x$elev_floor`.